# Resource_retriever package doesn't build in ROS2 Windows

Tags: ros2, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying to build ROS2 Eloquent for Windows using the guide:
https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Eloquent/Windows-Development-Setup/#install-additional-dds-implementations-optional

The problem occurs when I build the "resource_retriever" package, when the whole build fails.
In order to debug slightly I ran

```
colcon build --merge-install --packages-select resource_retriever --event-handler console_cohesion+
```

Resulting in

```
Starting >>> resource_retriever
--- output: resource_retriever
[6.968s] -- Found ament_cmake_ros: 0.8.0 (C:/dev/ros2_eloquent/install/share/ament_cmake_ros/cmake)
[7.375s] -- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: C:/Python37/python.exe
[8.640s] -- Found ament_index_cpp: 0.7.2 (C:/dev/ros2_eloquent/install/share/ament_index_cpp/cmake)
[8.703s] -- Found libcurl_vendor: 2.2.1 (C:/dev/ros2_eloquent/install/share/libcurl_vendor/cmake)
[8.796s] -- library: C:/dev/ros2_eloquent/install/opt/libcurl_vendor/bin/libcurl.dll
[9.234s] -- Configuring done
[9.828s] -- Generating done
[9.875s] -- Build files have been written to: C:/dev/ros2_eloquent/build/resource_retriever
[10.234s] Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.5.0+d4cbfca49 for .NET Framework
[10.234s] Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
[10.234s]
[11.125s] C:\dev\ros2_eloquent\install\opt\libcurl_vendor\bin\libcurl.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x310     [C:\dev\ros2_eloquent\build\resource_retriever\resource_retriever.vcxproj]
---
Failed   <<< resource_retriever [ Exited with code 1 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [12.6s]
  1 package failed: resource_retriever
```

No other errors come up until this point, and I have no idea how to solve it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347339/resource_retriever-package-doesn%27t-build-in-ros2-windows/) by [drkleppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/52788/drkleppe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on 2020-04-08**:
I'm also facing the same error. Please let us know if you're able to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug was fixed in https://github.com/ros/resource_retriever/pull/40 . It has not yet been backported to ROS Eloquent, but I would expect it to be in the next ROS Eloquent sync.

**Edit:** It has been backported to Eloquent, and is fixed as of version 2.2.2

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [webvenky](https://answers.ros.org/users/22361/webvenky/) on 2020-04-12**:
Making the changes made as in https://github.com/ros/resource_retriever/commit/e3896511fdab0b3e632cad8ff502a6f07d7b2b97 does the trick. Thank you.